# Sharing internet connection using ethernet switch

Tags: windows-7, router, ethernet, internet-connection

I use a TP-Link modem for my internet connection and use a switch to share the internet connection between two PCs. I previously had a Enterr switch that worked perfectly fine and recently stopped working. I got a similar switch but am now getting limited connectivity in both my PCs.The internet connection works well when one of the PCs are connected directly to the modem.

After going through a few posts here I tried changing the IP address manually but still got no solutions. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the new one a "managed switch" by any chance?
May be that could be one reason why it will not let any traffic through unless it is told to do so.
Is your TP link modem's internet line connected to the "up-link" port of your new switch?
Share the switch model number as well.... only then can we move further on this....
Is the copper cable that connects between the TP link and new switch in good condition?
Check all cables for quality... That has been the problem many a times for me....

Comment: Hi thanks, I have checked all the cables they work fine. ZyXEL ES 105 is the model of the switch. The switch worked well in the shop I purchased it from. So I believe it has something to do with my pc settings. I'm not sure what a managed switch means.

Comment: A managed switch is a programmable switch which requires the user to define certain ports and IP address for communication...

Comment: The box doesn't mention anything of that sort. I don't think its a managed switch as the shopkeeper didn't have to change any ip or port address.

Comment: If in case it is a managed switch what do I need to change?

Comment: Just saw ur switch on the website. It is. Not a managed switch. Can u.Pls  set two different IP address for the PCs like 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2. And see if u can ping one another. Next from one of the PCs ping ur TP link... If this will work u will get thru this

Comment: Hi thanks, I was able to ping one PC from the other but couldn't reach the modem. What should I mention in the default gateway when assigning the IP address for the PCs? The IP of the modem?

Comment: I checked my ipconfig with and without the modem connected to the switch. both the times I didn't see any IP address. I believe the switch isn't getting connected to the modem at all. I've checked the wires again they work perfectly fine. Do I have to reset my modem or something?

Comment: Hi, did u check the cable between the TP link and ES105 - is that a cross cable? This is what i learnt from my experience.Like devices - (switch to switch or modem to switch) - use cross cable. Unlike devices (switch to PC) - use straight cable [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). If you were using the same type of cable between all devices - it could one reason why this setup is not working... I appreciate your patience. If this was right then the next step is checking your switch "home" page... We will get to that if this proves us wrong.

Comment: Hi thanks again, I just checked. All my cables are crossover if what I've checked is right. I used this site http://www.littlewhitedog.com/content-8.html. But don't most ethernet switches available today work irrespective of the cable? Checked the switch's site too, has mentioned that all ports are Auto MDIX.

Comment: If all the cables are good, then we need to look into the user guide / manual of both the switch and modem. Can you please share? This should be very easy... I've helped so many of my friends in setting up networks for home / cybercafe'. Weird that i'm unable to get thru this...

Comment: The switch didn't have a manual with it. The modems pretty old not sure I have that too. What details do.you want me to share. I'll see if I can find them.

Comment: Modem being old, check if it will talk to the new switch over a cross cable. Give it a shot by using a straight cable. Also check if the modem needs some configuration to talk to the switch. That is all i can think of now. Good luck.

Comment: Any luck my friend? Did you make it work? Please update here - if it had started working

Comment: Nope. Haven't figured it out yet. Been a bit tied up. Have called the service guy this weekend. Hopefully he'll be able to solve it.